# image-scraper nodeJS. How to send callback function to result array

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, promise

I tried to build easy app to build img-parser and started to use library image-scraper([node-image-scraper](https://github.com/leon-vv/node-image-scraper)). And faced with a problem. The question is: How could I get final array of objects

```
scraper.scrape(function(image) {
        images_list.push(image);
})
```

promises - doesn't work, I tried to send call back inside parameter of functions it also not gave me result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a promise, then `scraper#scrape()` can be promisified.

```
var Scraper = require("image-scraper");

Scraper.prototype.scrapeAsync = function(ms) {
    var ref = this; // same coding style as in existing methods.
    var images = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ref.on('image', (image) => { images.push(image) });
        ref.on('end', () => { resolve(images) });
        // ref.on('error', reject); // unfortunately image-scraper doesn't emit an 'error' event.
        if(ms !== undefined) { // maybe timeout as substitute for error handler?
            setTimeout(() = {
                reject(`image-scraper timed out after ${ms} ms`);
            }, ms);
        }
        ref.scrape();
    });
}
```

*untested*

Call, eg :

```
const scraper = new Scraper('whatever');

scraper.scrapeAsync(30000).then((images) => {
    // process the `images` array here.
});
```

It should be reasonably simple to modify the image-scraper source to emit "error" events instead of logging errors. You will probably want separate events for `page_error` (fatal) and `image-error` (non-fatal).

There seems to be little point submitting a pull-request - last update was 2 years ago.

Comment: Which is the better library, for your opinion? Or It's better to build own parser using 'cheerio' or something else?

Comment: I'm not really an expert but `image-scraper` seems like a good basis. As far as I can tell, error emission is the main (only?) issue. Maybe start your own fork - certainly simpler than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `scraper.on` method to listen for the `end` event.

Note that your call to `.scrape(callback)` can also be replaced with `.on('image', callback)`.

```
var images = []

scraper.on('image', function (image) {
  images.push(image)
})

scraper.on('end', function () {
  console.log(images)
})
```

Comment: i run this code inside function - and it not made console.log(images). Maybe I do something wrong?